# Zappa deploy fails with AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'add_description'

Tags: python, zappa

Since a few days ago, `zappa deploy` fails with the following error (zappa version 0.50.0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2785, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/root/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 510, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/root/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 557, in dispatch_command
    self.update(self.vargs['zip'], self.vargs['no_upload'])
  File "/root/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 993, in update
    endpoint_configuration=self.endpoint_configuration
  File "/root/repo/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 2106, in create_stack_template
    self.cf_template.add_description('Automatically generated with Zappa')
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'add_description'
```

Comment: @Dominique unless you're using zappa as a library in a deployment script, which also causes this error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since version `3.0.0`, the package `troposphere` removed the deprecated `Template` methods (see the [changelog](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/main/CHANGELOG.rst)).

> Breaking changes: * Python 3.6+ (Python 2.x and earlier Python 3.x support is now deprecated due to Python EOL) * Remove previously deprecated Template methods.

The above issue can be fixed by adding `troposphere<3` in the requirements file.

Comment: I also had to delete my function on AWS console and redeploy.  Otherwise I was getting some Cloud Formation error.

Comment: In requirements.txt, I changed troposphere==3.0.3 to troposphere<3, ran `zappa update dev` but got the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: A related issue that many people face is with the most recent version of setuptools. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69337822/1855919

Answer (score 1):

The answer by nbeuchat might not work for everyone, an alternative solution that might help would be to change the line in venv/lib/python3.6{or 7,8, etc.}/site-packages/zappa/core.py from add_description() to set_description().

Troposphere updated add_description to set_description along with other previously deprecated template methods which is why you see the problem.

[Source](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/1000)

Comment: I had to do this as troposphere wouldn't install properly with pipenv and zappa 0.53.0