# Force Zappa to use API Gateway HTTP API instead of REST

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, zappa

I want to use AWS API Gateway HTTP API instead of old REST with my lambda functions, for pricing reasons.

Difference here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html

What is the option in Zappa for this?

```
prod:
  s3_bucket: mybucket
  project_name": myproject
  app_function: app.app
  aws_region: eu-west-3
  domain: my.domain.com
  memory_size: 128
  lambda_concurrency: 10
  runtime: python3.8
  timeout_seconds: 30
  exception_handler: zappa_sentry.unhandled_exceptions
  keep_warm: false
  async_resources: false
```

```sh
zappa update prod -s zappa_settings.yml
```

[EDIT]
Not sure if it's linked, but I encountered [Zappa deploy fails with AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'add_description'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391621/zappa-deploy-fails-with-attributeerror-template-object-has-no-attribute-add)
and then using this as `requirements.txt` (using `python3.8`):

```
flask==1.1.4
zappa==0.53.0
zappa_sentry==0.4.1
troposphere<3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Sept 2021, there is no support for HTTP API Gateways.  There is an issue created to add support here: https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/851