# Zappa deployment error - troposphere==2.7.1 didn't help AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'add_description'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

I have migrated my python project from 2.7 to 3.8. and I am trying to deploy using zappa.
But, as soon as it's starting updating Lambda function configs  it hits this error.

```
Updating Lambda function configuration..
Oh no! An error occurred! :(

==============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 3422, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 588, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 644, in dispatch_command
    self.vargs["docker_image_uri"],
  File "/Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 1194, in update
    endpoint_configuration=self.endpoint_configuration,
  File "/Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 2417, in create_stack_template
    self.cf_template.add_description("Automatically generated with Zappa")
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'add_description'
```

I found this question and tried to downgrade troposphere as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391621/zappa-deploy-fails-with-attributeerror-template-object-has-no-attribute-add)  but again I face a new error as below:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/leilakarimi/Projects/ATGWSams/venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/2q/m5qvgtkj1872r4695zkbpln80000gn/T/pip-install-w9uojyvq/troposphere_527f0b9692da4c9ca1d6451190752408/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/2q/m5qvgtkj1872r4695zkbpln80000gn/T/pip-install-w9uojyvq/troposphere_527f0b9692da4c9ca1d6451190752408/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/2q/m5qvgtkj1872r4695zkbpln80000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-hguo5f3y
         cwd: /private/var/folders/2q/m5qvgtkj1872r4695zkbpln80000gn/T/pip-install-w9uojyvq/troposphere_527f0b9692da4c9ca1d6451190752408/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    error in troposphere setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/a1/cfb1f6b2f271213da05fd5c67cda0256d7d841ba0edbfa815ae517c6235d/troposphere-2.2.0.tar.gz#sha256=b2e322063e2278e7d69822943d230b683ce9a0438db8ad017f610d344998453d (from https://pypi.org/simple/troposphere/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement troposphere==2.7.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for troposphere==2.7.1
```

Any thoughts/help is much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: unfortunately, no! as I mentioned in the post when I tried their solution it throws the second error

Comment: Hey! Have you also updated your zappa version?

Comment: yes I did... it was 0.48.2 and now is 0.53.0

Comment: That's strange. 0.53.0 uses [troposphere 3.0.2](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/compare/0.53.0...master#diff-4d7c51b1efe9043e44439a949dfd92e5827321b34082903477fd04876edb7552R77). Try to remove your explicit entry for `troposphere==2.7.1` and reinstall all packages and see if it works

Comment: no it didn;t. got back to first error message about template add_description ! :(

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The link I gave was the diff between master and 0.53.0. This means that the fix will be in the next version which is not yet released

Comment: all good downgraded zappa to 0.48.2 which was my previous working version and thankfully it's working with python 3.8.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

`setuptools` 58 broke support for `use_2to3`. Therefore, you should add `setuptools<58` to your requirements file along with `troposphere<3`. If you still get the same issue, downgrade setuptools first and then install troposphere with the other requirements.

Related question: [Error while downloading the requirements using pip install (setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100275/error-while-downloading-the-requirements-using-pip-install-setup-command-use-2)

Comment: Man, i love you! Spend all my afternoon with this.

Answer (score 0):

We have forked zappa and removed the pinned requirement for Werkzeug. Zappa project been restarted but they have been late to update. You can read how to do this at this [blog](https://codedissolved.com/deploying-flask-via-zappa/)